# Gerar uma matriz sem repetições

Tags: c, matriz

Preciso fazer um codigo que pega uma matriz e coloca numeros aleatórios nela, sem repetições. Estou conseguindo gerar a matriz, porem, ela continua tendo alguns numeros repetidos ;-;

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>
#define TAM 5


int verificar(int *matriz[TAM][TAM]){
    int c1, c2, c3, c4;

   for (c1=0; c1<TAM; c1++){
        for (c2=0; c2<TAM; c2++){
            for (c3=0; c3<c1; c3++){
                for (c4=0; c4<c2; c4++){
                    if (matriz[c1][c2] == matriz[c3][c4]){
                        matriz[c3][c4] = rand() % 99;
                        verificar(matriz);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

int main(){
    int matriz[TAM][TAM], c2, c, temp, c1, c3, c4;

    srand(time(NULL));
    for (c=0; c<TAM; c++){
        for (c2=0; c2<TAM; c2++){
            matriz[c][c2] = rand() % 99;
            verificar(matriz);
        }
    }

    for (c=0; c<TAM; c++){
        printf("\n");
        for (c2=0; c2<TAM; c2++){
            printf("%d ", matriz[c][c2]);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Eu até pensei em elaborar uma resposta, mas de fato isso é uma duplicata. Crie um array com os elementos de 0 a 99, embaralhe-os aleatoriamente e então pegue os 25 primeiros elementos desse array para popular a sua matriz.

Comment: @VictorStafusa Eu próprio ia responder exatamente com essa solução, mas comecei a pensar que quase de certeza já haveria uma duplicata, e rapidamente achei uma.

Comment: Se entendes inglês, podes consultar em detalhes [essa resposta](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/196017/unique-non-repeating-random-numbers-in-o1/196065#196065)